# Where to store some private data inside Swift Module, Cocoa Touch framework?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, access-levels, cocoa-touch

**I need to store some private data** (current session ticket or settings) **inside my current Swift module.** For the simple app the options usually are `NSUserDefaults` or some file on the disk so I don't need any app using my `Cocoa Touch Framework` to be able to access (at least modify) this data from outside, cause some app may clean it's own documents folder for some reasons and developer might simply not know about my data stored here. Same situation with `NSUserDefaults`.

**Do modules have it's own documents folder?**

**I'm just wondering, what is the correct way to do that?**

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: use keychain http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/01/05/using-keychain-to-store-passwords-ios-iphone-ipad

Answer (score 2):

A Swift module defines a framework. Frameworks get their own bundle (which they can use for static assets that ship with the framework) but I believe that there is no API guidance or convention defining where they should persist data that the framework wants to hide from the app.

If you look at Apple's [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW11), it only has a section on defining "App-specific" locations for persisting data. The Framework Programming Guide doesn't seem to say anything about defining locations that are per-framework.

Given that, what I would do in my framework code is just use the app-specific storage location, but put all of my framework's data under a subdirectory or distinctive key string that clearly marked it with the name of the framework and was likely to be unique. So instead of saving to the Application Support/ directory, I'd save to Application Support/MyFramework/.

This will stop your framework from stomping on the hosting application's data. It won't stop a malicious hosting application from inspecting what your framework is saving, but that's a much harder problem to solve. Also, a clumsily-written hosting application could erase your data if it just erased all of its own data with a wildcard, but that might be its intent.

UPDATE:

As the commenter suggested, the keychain is also a reasonable place. But the keychain's security infrastructure does not (I believe) actually cryptographically protect you from the hosting app. Nonetheless it is a key value store that the hosting app is less likely to completely purge by accident.

If you really want to try to hide larger quantities of your framework's data from the hosting app then, alternatively, you could explore using `URLForDirectory(_:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:)` to find a system-wide (rather than app-specific) temporary directory, and then hide your framework's data in there. But I think all of those directories are subject to deletion at will by the system, so it would only work if you were saving data that your framework could regenerate later, perhaps based on a smaller seed of data, stored in a place like the keychain.

The bottom line is if you're shipping a framework for other people to use, you cannot strongly hide anything from an application developer using the framework. They can attach a debugger. Then you lose. (If you want to go into the deep end on this, there's a whole area called "white box cryptography" that describes protecting data from an adversary that can completely observe your operations. This is the basis of modern DRM systems.)